# SQL on salesforce not applicable

Tags: sql, salesforce

I have this code on SQL and I am trying to use it in Salesforce. I get an error that it does not recognize the JOIN function.

Here is the code :

```
SELECT 
lu_table.Name, 
lu_table.id,
primary.Start_date,  
primary.end_date, 
secondary.metric
FROM primary
LEFT JOIN secondary
ON primary.xyz= secondary.xyz
LEFT JOIN lu_table
ON primary.id = lu_table.id
group by lu_table.Name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce has own query language named SOQL. This language has no `JOIN` function. Here is the [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/)

SOQL syntax:

```sql
SELECT fieldList [subquery][...]
[TYPEOF typeOfField whenExpression[...] elseExpression END][...]
FROM objectType[,...] 
    [USING SCOPE filterScope]
[WHERE conditionExpression]
[WITH [DATA CATEGORY] filteringExpression]
[GROUP BY {fieldGroupByList|ROLLUP (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)|CUBE (fieldSubtotalGroupByList)} 
    [HAVING havingConditionExpression] ] 
[ORDER BY fieldOrderByList {ASC|DESC} [NULLS {FIRST|LAST}] ]
[LIMIT numberOfRowsToReturn]
[OFFSET numberOfRowsToSkip]
[FOR {VIEW  | REFERENCE}[,...] ]
      [ UPDATE {TRACKING|VIEWSTAT}[,...] ]
```

**EDIT**

You query in SOQL it'd be something like that.

```
SELECT
    Start_date,
    end_date,
    (SELECT Id, Name FROM lu_table),
    (SELECT metric FROM secondary)
FROM primary
WHERE xyz IN (SELECT xyz FROM secondary WHERE condition)
AND Id IN (SELECT id FROM lu_table WHERE condition)
GROUP BY lu_table.Name;
```

But I'm not sure that in such form the query will not reach SF limits

Comment: So, how can I convert the left join of the 3 tables in SOQL.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, there is no tools for this. You need to convert it by yourself. I doubt there is a table, named 'primary'. It will be, probably, 'primary__c'.

Comment: @Pavel Slepiankou I ll try that until Tuesday and come back. Cheers

Comment: @PavelSlepiankou If there is no condition should I exclude this line : "WHERE condition"?

Comment: @ApoloRadomer yes, I included it only as an example

Comment: @PavelSlepiankou I am getting this error :
LandingzoneException [processError=VALIDATION_ERROR,Message=Error Code: INVALID_TYPE; Message: gross_CPM, gross_cost, Name FROM Internal_Line_Item__c), ^ ERROR at Row:9:Column:95 Didn't understand relationship 'Internal_Line_Item__c' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.; 
]

Comment: @ApoloRadomer please update your query in question with actual query which you use